# Secure Node-Red electron application with node-red-admin

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, node-red

I used [this](https://github.com/natcl/electron-node-red) GitHub repo to create a Node-Red desktop application with electron.
Now I want to add authentication to this application with node-red-admin. How can I do that?
Because I don't find any settings.js file in the build to add adminAuth to secure Node-Red

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings are not in a separate file, they are created as an object in `main.js` [here](https://github.com/natcl/electron-node-red/blob/a673babea94209927f9feb45f7582afb0b9dd393/main.js#L54)